# Ошибка при загрузке формы логина

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

При переходе на http://localhost:8080/ открывалась форма логина http://localhost:8080/login
Теперь вместо этого выдает ошибку, буду благодарен за любую помощь, ниже добавлю формы html и контроллеры:

```
    2020-07-24 13:42:41.838 ERROR 9452 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-9] Exception processing template "index": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.login" (template: "index" - line 21, col 34)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.login" (template: "index" - line 21, col 34)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'login' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:337) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Движок языка выражений Spring (`SpringEl`/`SpEl`) выдает ошибку о том, что вы пытаетесь получить значение поля `login` объекта, который равен `null` (`template: "index" - line 21, col 34`).

Если ранее при запросе `http://localhost:8080/` сразу отправляло пользователя на `http://localhost:8080/login`, то предполагаю, что ранее не был разрешен доступ всем пользователям к странице `/`. Думаю можно `.antMatchers("/", "/*.css").permitAll()` заменить на `.antMatchers("/").authenticated().antMatchers("/*.css").permitAll()`.

В случае, если вы хотите оставить доступ к `/` всем пользователям, то необходимо проверять, что `user` не `null`.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, милый человек! Помогло!)

Answer (score 0):

```
2020-07-24 13:42:41.841 ERROR 9452 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'login' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:337) ~[spring-expression-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_251]
```

Answer (score 0):

LoginController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailsService(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("ADMIN").password("ADMIN").roles("ADMIN")
        /*auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);*/
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
//                    .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/*.css").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
                    .and()
                .logout();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" type="text/css"/>-->
    <title>Admin panel</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/favicon.ico"/>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark  bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#nav-home">
        <span>User "</span><span th:text="${user.login}"/><span>" with role </span><span th:text="${user.roles}"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}">logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row min-vh-100">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills mt-2 container-fluid" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                <a sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')" class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab-p" data-toggle="tab" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">
                    Admin
                </a>
                <a sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('USER')" class="nav-item nav-link  " id="nav-profile-tab-p" data-toggle="tab" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">
                User
            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10"
             style="background: #edeef0">
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent-p">
                <div sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel"
                     aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab-p">
                    <h2>Admin panel</h2>
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="nav-home-tab" class="nat-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#users_table">Users table</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="nav-profile-tab" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#new_user">New User</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="users_table" class="tab-pane show active">
                            <h4 class="m-2">All users</h4>
                            <div class="row bg-light container">
                                <div class="container m-3">
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Id</th>
                                        <th>Login</th>
                                        <th>Password</th>
                                        <th>Role</th>
                                        <th>Edit</th>
                                        <th>Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
                                        <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${user.login}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${user.password}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${user.roles}"></td>
                                        <td><a th:data-target="'#modalEdit'+${user.id}" th:value="${user.id}" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info text-white">Edit</a></td>
                                        <td><a th:data-target="'#modalDelete'+${user.id}" th:value="${user.id}" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger text-white">Delete</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!--Добавление Пользователя-->
                        <div id="new_user" class="tab-pane fade border rounded" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                            <h4 class="m-2">Add New User</h4>
                            <div class="container-fluid bg-light">
                                <div class="row justify-content-center p-3">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <form th:action="@{/admin/adduser}" method="post">
                                            <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                                <label for="login">Login</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                                <label for="rolesAdd">Role</label>
                                                <select id="rolesAdd" class="custom-select" name="role_id" multiple required>
                                                    <tr th:each="role : ${roles}">
                                                        <td><option th:value="${role.getId()}" th:text="${role.getRole()}"></option></td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success d-block mx-auto">Add New User</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('USER')" class="tab-pane fade show" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab-p">
                    <div class="container ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 class="m-2">User information page</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row border rounded">
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center ml-2">
                                <h4 class="m-2">About user</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" style="background-color: white">
                            <div class="container m-3">
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Login</th>
                                        <th>Password</th>
                                        <th>Role</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td th:text="${user.id}"/>
                                        <td th:text="${user.login}" />
                                        <td th:text="${user.password}" />
                                        <td th:text="${user.roles}"/>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Редактирование пользователя-->
<div th:each="user: ${users}" class="modal fade" th:id="'modalEdit'+${user.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalEditLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalEditLabel">Edit</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col">
                            <form th:action="@{/admin/update/{id}(id=${user.id})}" method="post" name="id" th:value="${user.id}" th:id="'user'+${user.id}">
                                <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                    <label for="idUserUpdate">ID</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUserUpdate" name="id" th:value="${user.id}" disabled>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                    <label for="loginUserUpdate">Login</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginUserUpdate" name="login" th:value="${user.login}" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                    <label for="passwordUserUpdate">Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="passwordUserUpdate" name="password" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                    <label for="rolesEdit">Role</label>
                                    <select id="rolesEdit" class="custom-select" name="role_id" multiple required>
                                        <tr th:each="role : ${roles}">
                                            <td><option th:value="${role.getId()}" th:text="${role.getRole()}"></option></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="id" th:value="${user.id}" th:form="'user'+${user.id}">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--</editor-fold>-->

<!--<editor-fold desc="modal delete">-->
<div th:each="user: ${users}" class="modal fade" th:id="'modalDelete'+${user.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalDeleteLabel">Delete</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col">
                            <form th:action="@{/admin/delete}" method="post" th:id="'userDelete'+${user.id}">
                                <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                    <label for="idUserDelete">ID</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUserDelete" name="id" th:value="${user.id}" disabled>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                    <label for="loginUserDelete">Login</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginUserDelete" name="login" th:value="${user.login}" disabled>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                    <label for="passwordUserDelete">Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="passwordUserDelete" name="password" th:value="${user.password}" disabled>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center font-weight-bold">
                                    <label for="roleUserDelete">Role</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="roleUserDelete" name="role" th:value="${user.roles}" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="id" th:value="${user.id}" th:form="'userDelete'+${user.id}">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Login page</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/pdf/favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container p-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h4 class="p-2 font-weight-bold">Please sign in</h4>
            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">
                Invalid username and password.
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
            <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="login" required autofocus/>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" required/>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-2" type="submit"> Sign in </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```